# Putting commas int the String

Tags: java

Today, I have a problem with the comma. I want to put the commas in the String like this:

```
String before = "12345678901234";
String after = commaInString(before); //This is the function that I want to make, but with no luck yet.
System.out.println(after); // This should show 12,345,678,901,234
```

So, what I have to do now is make commaInString(String string) function, and I've made a test function below:

```
public static String commaInString(String string) {
        int stringSize = string.length(); 
        int fsize = stringSize % 3; 
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        int j = 0;
        for(int k=0;k<stringSize;k++) {
            if(fsize !=0 && k<fsize) j=0;
            else if(fsize !=0 && k==fsize) sb.append(",");
            j++;
            sb.append(string.substring(k,k+1)); 
            if(j%3==0 && (j+fsize)!=stringSize) sb.append(",");
        }

        string=sb.toString();
        return string;
    }
```

But, it only works on some of the numbers, and I don't know why. I cannot use the DecimalFormmat, as the number is too big to be an Integer. I want to put commas in 'String' itself. What arrangements can I make to the function above to fix this problem? Please help.

Comment: What do you mean "only works on some of the numbers"?  Which numbers does it not work for?  How does it not work for them?  Please [edit] your question to include complete information about your problem.

Comment: Is the number too big for `long` as well? So you could use `DecimalFormat`.

Comment: @azurefrog Ah, when I tried number with 6 stringSize, It worked. But, when I tried for the number with 11 stringSize, It doesn't work. The number I've tried was 51999027006, and the result was 51,99,902,7006. It was strange....

Comment: This looks WAY to complex for what you need.  Why not just walk through the number (you're doing it anyway) and insert into StringBuffer?

Comment: @Kayaman The number that I want to put comma on is very long, So I don't think long parameter can handle this...I reaaallly want to use DecimalFormat, though

Comment: @SangcheolYu then use `BigInteger`. It has arbitrary length. `DecimalFormat` supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close just edit this:

```
    if(fsize !=0 && k<fsize) j=0;
    else if(fsize !=0 && k==fsize){
        j=0;
        sb.append(",");
    }
```

Comment: Wow....I've missed the tiny bit......Thank you sooooo much for the help! I really appreciate it!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use `BigInteger` and any of the existing formatters, e.g.

```
BigInteger num = new BigInteger("12345678901234567890");
String formatted = String.format("%,d", num);
// 12,345,678,901,234,567,890
```

Comment: I didn't know about the BigInteger before now, but This can help as well! Thanks for the answer!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

i think the function below would meet your desires

```
public static String commaInString(String s) {
        StringBuilder reverse = new StringBuilder(s).reverse();
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 3)
            output.append(reverse.substring(i, Integer.min(i + 3, s.length()))).append(",");
        return output.reverse().deleteCharAt(0).toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringBuilder::insert](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,char)) instead to simplify your code

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        int x = 1234567890;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(commaInString(String.valueOf(x)));
            x /= 10;
        }
    }

    public static String commaInString(String string) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);
        for (int k = 3; k < string.length(); k += 3) {
            sb.insert(string.length() - k, ',');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1,234,567,890
123,456,789
12,345,678
1,234,567
123,456
12,345
1,234
123
12
1
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.